# Button at bottom disappears

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a very high possibility that a question similar to this has been asked earlier, but I couldn't figure out the related keywords to find the same.

I am making an application, and the layout I designed is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Scheduler" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressee"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/addresseeHint"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/scheduleDate"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/scheduleTime"
            android:inputType="time" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/smsText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/smsTextHint"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scheduleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/scheduleTextButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout which appears is as below:

[image]

What I want will look something like this:

[image]

The problem is the `Button` at the bottom (id:scheduleText) disappears, reason being the `layout_height` parameter of the `EditText` set just above it is `fill_parent`. But I guess I can't provide any particular value to it as then the layout will look different on different devices ?

How can I fix this bug ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi your EditText has a height of fill parent which makes it fill the parent and the button won't be visible so make it like this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/smsText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/smsTextHint"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

**UPDATE:**

I updated the answer to extend the edit text and fill the screen but let space for the button as well. The trick is to use weight..